# How to replace some indices of a vector with the same indices of another vector in R?

Tags: r

I have two vectors (in R), each with the same length. I want to replace all negative values in vector A with the corresponding indices in vector B. For example, if indices 5, 7, and 9 of vector A are negative values, I want to replace indices 5, 7 and 9 of vector A with indices 5, 7, and 9 in vector B.

Thanks so much!

Comment: or simply with ifelse: `ifelse(a<0, b, a)`

Answer (score 2):

Here is one quick way:

```
a <- c(1,2,3,4,-5,6,-7,8,-9 )
b <- c(5,5,5,5, 5,5, 5,5, 5)
a[ a<0 ] <- b[ a<0 ]
```

yields:

```
> a
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 5 8 5
```

For fastest results, use `a[ a<0 ] <- b[ a<0 ]`:

```
> microbenchmark(ifelse(a<0,b,a),a[ a<0 ] <- b[ a<0 ])
Unit: nanoseconds
                 expr  min   lq    mean median   uq   max neval
  ifelse(a < 0, b, a) 3137 3707 4497.14   3992 4277 33072   100
 a[a < 0] <- b[a < 0]  856 1141 1657.47   1426 1427 11120   100
```